# How do you remove shared hosting folder name from URL in ASP.NET Core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a website (http://jsoncore.net) that I am using to learn .NET Core 2 and I want to remove the shared hosting folder name from the URL that is added to links and sources. For example I add an Html.ActionLink like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(page.NavTitle, page.Slug, "Home")
```

and the system writes it to this:

```
<a href="/jsoncore/blog">Blog</a>
```

I want to remove the "/jsoncore" from the link URL so that it should look like this:

```
<a href="/blog">Blog</a>
```

Here are the routes defined in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {

            routes.MapRoute(
            "AdminController",
            "Admin/{action}",
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index"}
        );

            routes.MapRoute(
            "BlogController-BlogHome",
            "Blog/",
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" }
        );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "BlogController-Post",
                "Post/{id}",
                new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post", id = "" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "BlogController-Post-Tag",
                "Blog/Tag/{id}",
                new { controller = "Blog", action = "Tag", id = "" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "BlogController-Post-Category",
                "Blog/Category/{id}",
                new { controller = "Blog", action = "Category", id = "" }
                );


                routes.MapRoute(
                "HomeController",
                "{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "id?" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute("AccountController", "Login", new { controller = "Account", action = "Login"});

            routes.MapRoute("page", "{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Page", url = "" });



            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: What is the value of NavTitle and Slug?

Comment: "Blog" and "/blog" respectively

Comment: What do you have for routes set up in your Startup.cs (and [Route] attributes if you have any)? It does seem that there is a routing issue here. Also, the second parameter of `ActionLink` is the `actionName`, it shouldn't have a starting slash, it should be the name of the method in your controller.

Comment: I have a number of routes setup and none of them use "/jsoncore"

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include what you have for `app.UseMvc(routes => ...`?

Answer (score 1):

If the site is hosted in a virtual directory `/jsoncore/` there's no way to remove that from the URL, as it's actually part of the URL, i.e. you *need* that to get to the right place. Otherwise, the requests would hit the site hosted at just `http://jsoncore.net`, which isn't this application. It's called a *Universal Resource Locator* for a reason. Only the correct URL will work, which includes the `/jsoncore/` part, apparently.

Some shared hosting lets you bind to a domain or subdomain (although there'd probably be an upcharge for that). If that's available, that would be your best bet. Then, you can effectively host your site at the root of that domain/subdomain, without needing a path prefix.

Comment: Removing the shared hosting folder name is possible, as I do it for a number of ASP.NET websites I have developed. Normally I remove it in the web.config using a rewrite rule, but it doesn't seem to work for .NET Core 2

Comment: You can of course, simply "remove" it, but it won't go to the right place any more. That's my point. It's part of the URL for a reason. If you remove it from the URL, it's no longer the same URL, and will no longer hit your app, as your app only exists *under* `/jsoncore/`.

Comment: You can remove it and it will still go to the right place. Like I said, I have done it many, many times before.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, but that's simply not possible. A URL is a URL. You can't just clip some portion of it off and still end up at the same place. If the site is hosted in a virtual directory, that virtual directory path is a *core and crucial* part of the URL that you absolutely cannot remove and still end up at the right application. Period. End of story.

Comment: Ok, for example I have a website (genesiscore.net) that is on a server hosted at wolfcreektechnology.net and the is a website is in a shared hosting folder named "genesiscore". Through the web.config file I use the IIS rewrite module to remove the folder name from the URL and display     genesiscore.net everywhere instead of 'genesiscore.net/genesiscore/'